# OpenCV & EmguCV find rectangles

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I would like to analyse this image [Test Image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At53-PIsQ9AQgj94GkVSKlB6dijD?e=2P6nKE)

Goal is to find the rectangles (which are black) and use that geometric information to calculate the realworld position.

I found Emgu CV and its examples (I tried this [this](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp)). I not the same result which they show up.

In first place it would help me a lot to get the sample working. Maybe then its possible to get it working with my image.

kind regards

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello there is a other library called Aforge.NET and has a documentation for finding all the quadrilaterals on an image which will also find your rectangle